Are Dolbeault cohomology groups vector spaces over $\mathbb C$ or over $\mathcal O(M)$?

The Dolbeault cohomology groups of a complex manifold $M^{n}$ are defined by
$$H^{p, q}(M)=Z^{p, q}(M) / \bar{\partial} A^{p, q-1}(M)$$
where $Z^{p, q}$ is the kernel of $\bar{\partial}$ on $A^{p, q}(M)$. Here $p$, $q$ are integers between $0$ and $n$. (We adopt the convention $A^{p,-1}(M)=0$).
Note that a function $f$ is holomorphic if and only if $\bar{\partial} f=0$. More generally, a $(p, 0)$-form $\varphi$ is called a holomorphic $p$-form, if $\bar{\partial} \varphi=0$. So $H^{p, 0}(M)$ is the space of all (global) holomorphic $p$-forms on $M$ since $A^{p,-1}(M)=0$. More precisely,
$$H^{p, 0}(M)=\{\varphi\in A^{p,0}(M)~|~\bar{\partial} \varphi=0\}.$$

If Dolbeault cohomology groups are vector spaces over $\mathbb C$, let $\varphi$ be a holomorphic $p$-form. For any holomorphic function $f$, $f\varphi$ is also holomorphic. Since $f$ may not be constant, $H^{p, 0}(M)$ is infinite-dimensional. I think this is unreasonable. So are Dolbeault cohomology groups vector spaces over $\mathcal O(M)$? Any help would be appreciated!

Dolbeault cohomology groups are usually considered as vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$. If $\varphi$ is a holomorphic $p$-form and $f$ a holomorphic function, then $f \, \varphi$ is indeed also a holomorphic $p$-form. But this does not always imply that $H^{p,0}(M)$ is infinite-dimensional. For example, all holomorphic functions on compact complex manifolds are constant.
